# Circuit to share a pin

Tags: logic-gates, buffer

I ran out of pins on my MCU, and for that reason I want to share one pin, so it act as an input (data from a sensor) in certain part of my program, and as an output (chip select for SPI) in another part of my program.

I have used this TI SN74LVC1G125, Single buffer with 3-state outputs, as in the diagram below:
[image: schematic]

1. The MCU shared pin is marked as MULTI_DO_SD
2. The input pin is marked CSI_D0
3. The output pin is marked SD_CS

When signals comes in on CSI_DO, it sets OE high, preventing data going from A to Y.
When MULTI_DO_SD is used for output, D1 prevents data to run to CSI_DO, and inadvertently set OE high. R8 keeps OE low, allowing the output to go through to SD_CS.

It worked "fine" without R23, but SD_CS was jumping up and down. The datasheets says that Y is "undefined" when OE is high, so I tried to add R23, pulling the line down, but then SD_CS doesn't go high at all.

[image: datasheet]

What am I missing?

## EDIT 1

The MCU pin is on a ESP32:
[image: ESP32]

The Input pin is a data channel (0) on a CSI Camera:
[image: Camera Connection]

The Output pin is a Chip Select for a SD Card:
[image: SD Card Slot]

## EDIT 2

I have update the table above to the wanted outcome in red:
[image]

Comment: To further understand what you even want to achieve, please show also the pin you want to multiplex and the two subcircuits that are multiplexed.

Comment: Please create a table (like the one above) that shows all inputs and desired outputs of the circuit.

Comment: Google "I/O expander".   There are chips available to do what you want without you having to reinvent the wheel

Comment: The CS signal of SD cards is active low, so your R23 should go to VCC. How will you distinguish that from your input CSI_D0?

Comment: @KyleB, I don't want to use an I/O expander, because I then have to rewrite somebody else's SD and Camera libraries.

Comment: @Jens, I didn't think of that!!! And I can only add a NOR gate after the Y, if I can easily get the SD library to invert its use of the CS, looking into that...

Answer (score 1):

| CSI_D0 | MULTI_D0_SD | output: SD_CS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| L | L | L |
| L | H | H |
| H | L | L |
| H | H | L |

This is a NOR gate with one inverted input.
You could combine an inverter and a NOR gate, but you have the complete function in the (SN)74LVC1G97.